# jaxb unmarshalling with namespace

Tags: java, xml-parsing, namespaces, jaxb

This is my xml, need to  convert it into java. I had used jaxb

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lm:order Id="PLG24M240U" JD="" aCount="2" SUCount="1" xmlns:lm="http://www.ae.com/Event/Load">
  <lm:master>
   <lm:ID>3</lm:ID>
    <lm:Number>313</lm:Number>
    <lm:ANumber>323</lm:ANumber>     
  </lm:master>
  <lm:detail>
    <lm:ID>3</lm:ID>
    <lm:Number>3131</lm:Number>
    <lm:ANumber>3232</lm:ANumber>      
  </lm:detail>
 <lm:detail>
    <lm:ID>3</lm:ID>
    <lm:Number>3131</lm:Number>
    <lm:ANumber>3232</lm:ANumber>    
  </lm:detail>
  <lm:detail>
    <lm:ID>3</lm:ID>
    <lm:Number>313</lm:Number>
    <lm:ANumber>323</lm:ANumber>    
  </lm:detail>
</lm:order>
```

And throwing the following exception
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.ae.com/Event/Load", local:"Order"). Expected elements are <{}lm:Order>

This is my unmarshalling code

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Order.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Order order = (Order) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(order );
```

Order Pojo class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "lm:Order")
public class OrderPay {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String Id;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String JD;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String aCount;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String pCount;
    /*@XmlElement
    private Master master;
    @XmlElement
    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();*/

}
```

Can you please help me in reading also, currently reading through file,  need to read as an XML String.

Comment: @isim : ya its a typo, no compile time error in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The namespace attribute `xmlns:lm="http://www.ae.com/Event/Load"` might be the culprit here. In order to specify the namespace prefix, you can add the [`@XmlSchema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html) annotation to a `package-info.java` file like this:

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.ae.com/Event/Load",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED),
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="lm", namespaceURI="http://www.ae.com/Event/Load")})  

package your.package;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Comment: ya that error is not there now. But response is giving null. System.out.println(order.getACount ); is null

Comment: StringReader reader = new StringReader( "// whole xml "); jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Order.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Order order = (Order) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
System.out.println(order);

Comment: @Rosh I don't see an `aCount` attribute in your XML; only a `Count` attribute. Are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: No that is typo. The response value is null only.

Comment: @Rosh So you mean `System.out.println(order);` is `null`? Did you change your `@XmlRootElement(name = "lm:Order")` to just `@XmlRootElement(name = "Order")`?

Comment: yes, changed, order is not null, order.getAcount is null

Comment: @Rosh Try add this `@XmlAttribute(name='aCount')` to your `private String aCount;`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61158/discussion-between-rosh-and-isim).

Comment: Having a class inside Orderimport javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Master")
public class WorkOrderMaster {
 
 @XmlElement(name="ID")
 private String iD;
 
 private String Number; } Error : Class has two properties of the same name "ID"