# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException iccurs when unmarshalling an XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use the below code to unmarshal an XML using JAXB. responseXML contains the XML string returned from a web service call.

```
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(responseXML);
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestResponse.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Object idResponse = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

Below is the Exception which occurs when unmarshalling.

```
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
  - with linked exception:
 [Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
 Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
 Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ]
```

Someone help to work on this.

below is the TestResponse class which is auto generated from an XSD

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "responseCode",
    "responseDescription",
    "responsemessage"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "TestResponse")
public class TestResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String responseCode;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String responseDescription;
    protected String responsemessage;


    /**
     * Gets the value of the responseCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the responseCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResponseCode(String value) {
        this.responseCode = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the responseDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResponseDescription() {
        return responseDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the responseDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResponseDescription(String value) {
        this.responseDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the responsemessage property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getResponsemessage() {
        return responsemessage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the responsemessage property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setResponsemessage(String value) {
        this.responsemessage = value;
    }


}
```

here is the sample XML

```
<a:TestResponse xmlns:a="http://esm.mtn.co.za/data/commonbusiness/TestValidate">
    <a:responseCode>0</a:responseCode>
    <a:responseDescription>Success</a:responseDescription>
    <a:responsemessage>Success</a:responsemessage>  
</a:TestResponse>
```

Comment: Please post your XML and the corresponding class (TestResponse).

Comment: You're missing the `@XmlElement` annotation at the `responsemessage` field?

Comment: @XmlElement(required = true) annotation is added only if the field is required. That's an auto generated file from xsd.

Answer (score 1):

I think the namespace in the XML is causing a problem for parsing. Try to specify the namespace in package-info.java and mention the prefix as "a" in there. You can check more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html).

You could check a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819934/jaxb-unmarshalling-with-namespace)

Comment: The response XML returned from my web service call had some issue which caused the exception when unmarshaling it. When I removed some unused sections from the XSD file, this worked.

Comment: Great ! Still, you could mark the sections which are optional in the XSD as optional using minOccurs attribute (that is, if these sections can appear again, in some other responses its better to mark them as optional rather than removing(I know, that's not what you asked for)).

Comment: Since I auto generate the XSD, optional fields are automatically marked thus they are annotated in the generated java files as well. Having the unused fields annotated as that didn't make any difference in resolving the issue. I use eclipselink within my project. I doubt it can be one reason for this.