# How can I unmarshal an XML response to 2 java objects using JAXB when there are 2 namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, xmlhttprequest, jaxb, feign

Thank you for taking the time to read.

My goal is to deserialize the response from an API request into 2 usable java objects.

I am sending an POST request to an endpoint to create a job in our schedule. The job is created successfully and the following XML is returned in the body:

```
<entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
    <id>0</id>
    <title>Job has been created.</title>
    <source>com.tidalsoft.framework.rpc.Result</source>
    <tes:result xmlns:tes="http://www.auto-schedule.com/client">
        <tes:message>Job has been created.</tes:message>
        <tes:objectid>42320</tes:objectid>
        <tes:id>0</tes:id>
        <tes:operation>CREATE</tes:operation>
        <tes:ok>true</tes:ok>
        <tes:objectname>Job</tes:objectname>
    </tes:result>
</entry>
```

When I attempt to only capture the elements **id**, **title**, and **source** the data is captured successfully. The problem is when I introduce the child object, which attempts to capture the data in the **tes:result** element.

Here's what the parent POJO looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String source;

    ResponseDetails result;

    public Response() {}
}
```

and here is the child object:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResponseDetails {

    @XmlElement(name = "tes:message")
    String message;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "tes:objectid")
    String objectid;

    @XmlElement(name = "tes:operation")
    String operation;

    @XmlElement(name = "tes:ok")
    String ok;

    @XmlElement(name = "tes:objectname")
    String objectname;
}
```

Finally, here is the package-info.java file I am using:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://purl.org/atom/ns#",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.netspend.raven.tidal.request.response;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: Your Java code doesn't correctly specify the namespaces
corresponding to the inner XML element

```
<tes:result xmlns:tes="http://www.auto-schedule.com/client">
    <tes:message>Job has been created.</tes:message>
    <tes:objectid>42320</tes:objectid>
    <tes:id>0</tes:id>
    <tes:operation>CREATE</tes:operation>
    <tes:ok>true</tes:ok>
    <tes:objectname>Job</tes:objectname>
</tes:result>
```

The `<tes:result>` XML element has the namespace `"http://www.auto-schedule.com/client"`.
The namespace prefix `tes:` itself is irrelevant for Java.
(XML namespace prefixes were invented only for better readability of the XML code.)
Therefore in your `Response` class, instead of just writing

```
ResponseDetails result;
```

you need to write

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.auto-schedule.com/client")
ResponseDetails result;
```

See also the javadoc of [`XmlElement.namespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#namespace--).

Also all the XML sub-elements within the `<tes:result>` are specified
with this namespace `"http://www.auto-schedule.com/client"`.
Therefore, also inside your `ResponseDetails` you have to correct
the namespace stuff. For example, instead of

```
@XmlElement(name = "tes:message")
String message;
```

you need to write

```
@XmlElement(name = "message", namespace = "http://www.auto-schedule.com/client")
String message;
```

You may also omit the `name = "message"` and simply write

```
@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.auto-schedule.com/client")
String message;
```

because JAXB picks up this name from your Java property name `message`.

And similar for all the other properties in this class.

Comment: This was exactly the solution. Especially thank you for pointing out that the "tes" preceding the element name is irrelevant. Thank you very much.